# Add a service in Mac Finder using CLI

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I write a Python script and I want to add it as a service item in Mac Finder.
I know I can open `Automator` window and set it. 
But I need a command line way. I search the method for a long time and still get nothing...

Do anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.
(Using python, apple script or any builtin CLI tool is also acceptable to me)

Comment: You can use Automator's action called "Run Shell Script" and choose Python as the language. Doesn't this work for you?  You want the service to be available in the Mac Finder?  What exactly does your Service need to do?

Comment: I want "Add script as a service to Finder" this action can be achieved in "Command Line Interface".

Comment: Here is a link with other links that I have been using to try to understand services better: http://www.learnbymac.com/wiki/index.php?title=Services_Menu

Comment: A service is registered by an app or package (workflow) registering aa service provider. This is partly done in it's info plist where it has a service array with the correct info for the service. I.e menu text that will be displayed. There is also an entry of the name of the method (function if you will) that the application/workflow has in it's code that will be run when the service is used. And the code in the application/workflow will also have to register an object (possibly it's self ) as a service provider. I cannot think of a way without using this method to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

To go with my comment here is a very basic example.

Which is to show you how services are registered, even the Automator ones.
And why I think you may not be able to do what you want.

Using Xcode I have created a new project.

Code in the .m file:

```
    //
//  AppDelegate.m
//  testServiceExample
//
//  Created by Mark Hunte on 02/09/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Mark Hunte. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];//Registers a given object as the service provider.
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();//Causes the services information for the system to be updated.
}



-(void) runAService:(NSPasteboard *)pboard userData:(NSString *)userData error:(NSString **)error {

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] ) {
        NSArray *files = [pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];


         NSLog(@" files %@", files);

    }

    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
    }

@end
```

Note the :

```
[NSApp setServicesProvider:self];//Registers a given object as the service provider.
        NSUpdateDynamicServices();//Causes the services information for the system to be updated.
```

Then I added the Array to the applications info-plist

[image]

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>Service Test</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>runAService</string>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.item</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

`<string>Service Test</string>` menu displayed

`<string>runAService</string>` method to run in the application

`<string>public.item</string>` objects that the service will work on

The first run of the app (double clicking will register the service to the system. But I make sure it is checked in the keyboard shortcuts.

The result from the NSLog can be seen in the console.app which will list the files paths

---

So even if I could add a item using something like defaults write to the plist file that holds the registered applications in the system prefs services. I doubt anything would actually work without any of the above.

Obviously the Automator application can write the correct info to a the plist file and the **runAservice** method.

The actual method in a service workflows name is: ***runWorkflowAsService***.

Thinking about it. You can write and build apps from the command line. And have it run you python But it is a lot of trouble to go to.

For more info on services see the apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1)