# How do I enable Services which operate on selected Files and Folders

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to enable Services which operate on selected `Files and Folders` similar to those which can be invoked in Finder.

I have the following based on the `Services Implementation Guide` which works, but only for Text etc

```
+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    /* Make sure code only gets executed once. */
    if (initialized == YES) return;
    initialized = YES;

    NSArray *sendTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType];
    [NSApp registerServicesMenuSendTypes:sendTypes returnTypes:nil];
    NSLog(@"initialize MyTableView");
}
- (id)validRequestorForSendType:(NSString *)sendType returnType:(NSString *)returnType {
    NSLog(@"validRequestorForSendType %@%@", sendType, returnType);
    if ([sendType isEqual:NSStringPboardType]) {
            return self;
    }
    return [super validRequestorForSendType:sendType returnType:returnType];
}
```

How do I implement URL?

The documentation states

> Your NSResponder object can register any pasteboard data type, public
>   or proprietary, common or rare. If it handles the public and common
>   types, of course, it has access to more services. For a list of
>   standard pasteboard data types, see NSPasteboard Class Reference.

There seems to be no corresponding pasteboard data type. I have tried `NSURL`, `NSURL class`
`NSFilenamesPboardType` partially works, but does not show all the Services Finder does, and seems to belong to (OS X v10.5 and earlier)

**Edit Clarification**

I have been following the `Services Implementation Guide`, which seems to have 3 steps

1.Registering Objects for Services

```
NSApp registerServicesMenuSendTypes: returnTypes:
```

2.Validating Services Menu Items

```
validRequestorForSendType:returnType:
```

3.Sending Data to the Service

```
writeSelectionToPasteboard:types:
```

I have got the first 2 to partially work (although I cannot get the same Menu I see in Finder when a File is selected in particular the `Files and Folders` )

The 3rd seems to be the sticking point
This seems to be supported for `NSTextView`, but deprecated for `NSObject`

I am really looking for some idea how to use Services for `Files and Folders` in the same way many other applications do.

[image: Desired Services Menu]

Comment: This question is confusing me. Do you want to display the same "Services" menu that appears in the Application menu (e.g. under the "TextEdit" menu when running TextEdit; under the "Safari" menu when running Safari).

Comment: What finder menu are you talking about??

Comment: also look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18579656/261305

Comment: I have no problem creating Services. What I want is to add to an application a Services Menu similar to the image edited above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this work, and am posting the result for the benefit of others who may want to do similar.

The first 3 methods are in my Class which subclassed a View

```
+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    /* Make sure code only gets executed once. */
    if (initialized == YES) return;
    initialized = YES;

    [NSApp registerServicesMenuSendTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL] returnTypes:nil];
}
- (id)validRequestorForSendType:(NSString *)sendType returnType:(NSString *)returnType {
    if ([sendType isEqual:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL]) {
            return self;
    }
    return [super validRequestorForSendType:sendType returnType:returnType];
}
- (BOOL)writeSelectionToPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard types:(NSArray *)types {
    if([self.keyDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(writeSelectionToPasteboard:types:)])
        return [self.keyDelegate writeSelectionToPasteboard:pboard types:types];
    return FALSE;
}
```

The last in the delegate to actually write to the pasteboard.

```
- (BOOL)writeSelectionToPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard types:(NSArray *)types {
    return [pboard setString:[[[self selectedFile] url] absoluteString] forType:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeFileURL];
}
```

There was a certain amount of guesswork/experimentation because the requirements do not seem to be clearly specified.
This is simple implementation, because I am only interested in one type.